# Pandas rank function with custom method OR limit number of decimals in mean calcultation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

EDIT : my question is not well asked nor enough detailed. I am redoing it better, please let me time to do it

EDIT 2 : My question was not clear enough nor adapted to my problem, I solved my problem in a different way. I cannot delete the question, but please don't bother answering, I messed up the question.

---

My goal is to perfom a rank calculation on a pandas dataframe with the `average` method, BUT the average calculation should be round to 3 decimals.

Why : I am translating a script from another language to Python, and in this language the mean function automatically rounds result to 3 decimals. Pandas doesn't. So in order to get exactly (and I must) the same result in Python, I need to either :

- pass a custom `method` argument to the `rank` function, with this custom method being a rounded mean
- force Python to only take 3 decimals when calculating means all the time (which would be great for my script).

Is any of these ideas possible ?

In the first language :

```
mean(mydata['mycolumn']) = 1360.045
```

In Python :

```
mydata.mycolumn.mean() = 1360.0448559218441
```

So in consequence, when calculating the rank of `mycolumn` (grouped by another column, idk if it matters), the ranks are not the same and the final result is different between the two languages.

Comment: I'd be interested in how you solved it eventually, and also I think the "*force Python to only take 3 decimals when calculating means all the time (which would be great for my script)*" part of the answer was interesting (independently of your real use case). You might want to turn this into a useful Q/A ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom method for your DataFrames:

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

def round3mean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.round(3).mean(*args, **kwargs)
    # or, depending on the order of computation in your other langage
    # self.mean(*args, **kwargs).round(3)

PandasObject.round3mean = round3mean
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1.1234567, 1.1234567, 1.1234567]})

df.mean()

col1    1.123457
dtype: float64

df.round3mean()

col1    1.123
dtype: float64
```

Combined with `rank`:

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(4, 3)), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

out = df.round3mean().rank()
```

*NB. you can also create a `round3rank` method to do this directly if you want.*

```
from pandas.core.base import PandasObject

def round3rank(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.mean(*args, **kwargs).round(3).rank()

PandasObject.round3rank = round3rank

df.round3rank()
```

Output:

```
col1    1.0
col2    3.0
col3    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom function:

```
custom_func = lambda x: round(x.mean(), 3)

out = mydata.groupby('col')['mycolumn'].agg(custom_func)
```

Comment: It would work if my problem was to calculate means, but I need to calculate ranks.

Comment: I think my question is not well asked and enough detailed. I'm going to redo it.